# Foundation 5 reveal won't open (Appended to BODY with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I've been searching SO and the Web for an answer on my issue, but couldn't find anything.

I have appended a reveal modal to the BODY with jQuery. Now when I click on the button which opens the modal, only the overlay is shown. I just can't figure out what is causing the problem.

I have created an example on codepen. [http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/KhsGH](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KhsGH)

"Open Modal 1" should open the programmatically appended modal.
"Open Modal 2" opens the modal, that is placed directly in the BODY. (This one is just to show that it usually works)

Maybe one of you guys can help me with this.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:
This error is displayed in Firebug:

TypeError: settings is undefined
this.show(modal, settings.css.open);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call foundation after you have appended the modal content div

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("body").append('<div class="reveal-modal small foo1" data-reveal><p>Test Reveal</p></div>');

         $(document).foundation();

         $(document).on('click', '.trigger_foo1',function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $(".foo1").foundation('reveal', 'open');
         });

         $(document).on('click', '.trigger_foo2',function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $(".foo2").foundation('reveal', 'open');
         });  
    });
```